# No route matches error. Whats wrong with this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I'm newbie on rails and getting an error while try to add new method on my controller :(
I have a controller under admin path;

```
Admin::MyUsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :......

def index
  redirect_to :action => :show_my_action
end

def show_my_action
  ...
  ...
end
```

My controller like this but not this exactly.
In my routes.rb

```
namespace "admin" do
  resources :my_users do
    get "show_my_action"
  end
end
```

When my routes.rb is like this, im getting error => No route matches {:action=>"show_my_action", :controller=>"admin/my_users"}

```
namespace "admin" do
  resources :my_users do
    get "show_my_action", :on => :collection
  end
end
```

when my routes.rb like this then no error :S
Why im getting this error. I can use first declaration for other controllers which is on root path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding actions to RESTful actions, if you don't specify a collection, or a member, the route can't know what you want. If you define like this:

```
namespace "admin" do
  resources :my_users do
    get "show_my_action"
  end
end
```

How can routes know which route you want:

```
my_users/show_my_action, or my_users/:id/show_my_action
```

So, you need to specify it's member or collection:

```
namespace "admin" do
  resources :my_users do
    get "show_my_action", :on => :collection
  end
end
```

will have route: `my_users/show_my_action`, and:

```
namespace "admin" do
  resources :my_users do
    get "show_my_action", :on => :member
  end
en
```

will have route: `my_users/:id/show_my_action`

You can check at [Adding More RESTful Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify whether the action is on a member or a collection. If it's on a member then your URL is `admin/my_users/:id/show_my_action`. If it's on a collection then it's `admin/my_users/show_my_action`. Read up on it here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html